# How long before http timeouts when server sends response slowly?

Tags: http

The standard HTTP timeout seems to be 30 seconds, if the server does not respond at all. But what is the "standard" timeout if a server is responding, but sending the response very slowly? When does the client give up? When it reaches a certain time between packets? Never?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP does not standardize on a timeout; nothing prevents clients from waiting forever. Some clients may do an application-level timeout of 30 seconds, but my Firefox, for example, shows `network.http.response.timeout` as 300 seconds.

The lack of standard applies even more to slow responses. For example, various scanning and reverse proxies employ trickling techniques to drip feed a few bytes to the client to prevent it from timing out while they do heavy processing. Usually 100 bytes or so every ten seconds suffices, though of course it's very much ad-hoc (see also comment above on lack of standard).

Comment: I actually need to do heavy processing on the server. That's why I asked.

Comment: Understood. I'd definitely consider some form of trickling or AJAX-y approach. If your server is end-user facing then you might want to show progress irrespective of timeouts on the browser, but if we look at purely HTTP side of it, then no server data within 30 seconds is always a risk. Some aggressive clients might time out.

Comment: I'm doing serial batch image processing, returning data as soon as an image is processed. It should work.